# Awk to add wildcards to a text string read from file - Regex

Tags: php, regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file containing a list of databases and tables. Some lines are only 'databases' and some others are 'databases and tables' it looks like this: file.txt

```
database1 table1
database1 table4
database2
database3 table2
```

I'm reading this file with a bash script and parsing the strings to then call a function to backup my databases(this is not relevant). Here is how i'm parsing the strings:

```
s=$(awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='.' ORS='|' file.txt)
LIST="${s%|}"

echo "$LIST"
database1.table1|database1.table4|database2|database3.table2
```

But what I need to add some wildcards after each sub-string. For instance

```
database1.table1 needs to be database1.table1.*
database1.table4 needs to be database1.table4.*
```

But

```
database2 needs to be database2*.*
```

In other words when there is only database with no table i need to add `*.*` at the end and when there is a database.table i need to add `.*` at the end.
The expected output will be

```
database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*
```

I know this is an odd question but i need to solve this problem to start using my mysql backup script.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bash-3.2$ awk '{ sep = (NR > 1) ? "|" : "" } NF == 1 { printf("%s%s*.*", sep, $1); } NF == 2 { printf("%s%s.%s.*", sep, $1, $2) }' file.txt; echo
database1.table1.*|database1.table4.*|database2*.*|database3.table2.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix

```
LIST=$(awk '{$2=(NF>1)?$2 ".*":"*.*"}1' OFS='.' ORS='|' file.txt|sed 's/|$//')
```